# What is the solutions of the following 1D diffusion equality using Crank–Nicolson method?

Tags: heat-transfer, finite-element-method, matlab

Through my research I faced to the following equality and need to find $c_i^{t+1}$. Moreover, I found that it can be solved by Crank–Nicolson  method (see  here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank%E2%80%93Nicolson_method). Unfortunately I could not understand how to use the method and I did not calculate the solutions. Any one can help me to calculate the solutions? Thanks in advance.
\begin{align*}
    \frac{c_{i}^{t+1}-c_{i}^{t}}{\Delta t}&=\frac{D}{2}(\frac{c_{i+1}^{t}-2c_{i}^{t}+c_{i-1}^{t}}{{\Delta x}^{2}}+
    \frac{c_{i+1}^{t+1}-2c_{i}^{t+1}+c_{i-1}^{t+1}}{{\Delta x}^{2}} )
    \\&-\frac{V}{2}(\frac{c_{{\color{red}i} {\color{red}+}{\color{red}1}}^{t}-c_{i-1}^{t}}{2\Delta x}+
    \frac{c_{i+1}^{t+1}-c_{i-1}^{t+1}}{2\Delta x} )
\end{align*}
My working on this problem:

The Crank–Nicolson method
\begin{align}\label{1}
    \frac{\partial C}{\partial t} = D_x \frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial x^2} - U_x \frac{\partial C}{\partial x} \,(1)
\end{align}

We know that:
\begin{align}\label{2}
    \frac{\partial C}{\partial t} \Rightarrow \frac{C_i^{t+1} - C_i^t}{\Delta t},\,(2)
\end{align}

\begin{align}\label{3}
    \frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial x^2} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2 (\Delta x)^2}\left(
        (C_{i+1}^{t+1} - 2 C_i^{t+1} + C_{i-1}^{t+1}) + 
        (C_{i+1}^t - 2 C_i^t + C_{i-1}^t)
        \right),\,(3)
\end{align}

\begin{align}\label{4}
    \frac{\partial C}{\partial x} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}\left(
        \frac{(C_{i+1}^{t+1} - C_{i-1}^{t+1})}{2 (\Delta x)} + 
        \frac{(C_{i+1}^t - C_{i-1}^t)}{2 (\Delta x)}
        \right),\,(4)
\end{align}
Now putting (2), (3), (4) in (1) and $D_x=D$ ,$U_x=V$ we get
\begin{align*}\label{5}
    \frac{c_{i}^{t+1}-c_{i}^{t}}{\Delta t}&=\frac{D}{2}(\frac{c_{i+1}^{t}-2c_{i}^{t}+c_{i-1}^{t}}{{\Delta x}^{2}}+
    \frac{c_{i+1}^{t+1}-2c_{i}^{t+1}+c_{i-1}^{t+1}}{{\Delta x}^{2}} )
    \\&-\frac{V}{2}(\frac{c_{i+1}^{t}-c_{i-1}^{t}}{2\Delta x}+
    \frac{c_{i+1}^{t+1}-c_{i-1}^{t+1}}{2\Delta x} )
\end{align*}

So it is obtained
\begin{align}
        \frac{c_{i}^{t+1}-c_{i}^{t}}{\Delta t}&=\frac{D}{2{\Delta x}^{2}}({c_{i+1}^{t}-2c_{i}^{t}+c_{i-1}^{t}}{}+
    {c_{i+1}^{t+1}-2c_{i}^{t+1}+c_{i-1}^{t+1}}{} )
    -\frac{V}{4\Delta x}({c_{i+1}^{t}-c_{i-1}^{t}}{}+
    {c_{i+1}^{t+1}-c_{i-1}^{t+1}} )
\end{align}
$$\Rightarrow$$
\begin{align*}
c_{i}^{t+1}=c_{i}^{t}+\frac{D\Delta t}{2{\Delta x}^{2}}({c_{i+1}^{t}-2c_{i}^{t}+c_{i-1}^{t}}{}+
{c_{i+1}^{t+1}-2c_{i}^{t+1}+c_{i-1}^{t+1}}{} )
-\frac{V\Delta t}{4\Delta x}({c_{i+1}^{t}-c_{i-1}^{t}}{}+
{c_{i+1}^{t+1}-c_{i-1}^{t+1}} )
\end{align*}

Now putting $\lambda = \frac{D \Delta t}{2 \Delta x^2}$ and $\sigma = \frac{V \Delta t}{4 \Delta x}$ we have;

\begin{align*}
    c_{i}^{t+1}=c_{i}^{t}+\lambda({c_{i+1}^{t}-2c_{i}^{t}+c_{i-1}^{t}}{}+
    {c_{i+1}^{t+1}-2c_{i}^{t+1}+c_{i-1}^{t+1}} )
    -{\sigma}({c_{i+1}^{t}-c_{i-1}^{t}}+
    {c_{i+1}^{t+1}-c_{i-1}^{t+1}} )
\end{align*}
$$\Rightarrow$$
\begin{align*}
(1+2\lambda)c_{i}^{t+1}=(1-2\lambda)c_{i}^{t}+(\lambda-\sigma)c_{i+1}^{t}+(\lambda+\sigma)c_{i-1}^{t}+(\lambda-\sigma)c_{i+1}^{t+1}+(\lambda+\sigma)c_{i-1}^{t+1}
\end{align*}
$$\Rightarrow$$

\begin{align*}
    c_{i}^{t+1}=\frac{1}{(1+2\lambda)}\big((1-2\lambda)c_{i}^{t}+(\lambda-\sigma)c_{i+1}^{t}+(\lambda+\sigma)c_{i-1}^{t}+(\lambda-\sigma)c_{i+1}^{t+1}+(\lambda+\sigma)c_{i-1}^{t+1}\big)
 \end{align*}

Now I do not know coefficient matrixes cited here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank%E2%80%93Nicolson_method) how make and how the closed form for $c_{i}^{t+1}$ is obtained?

Comment: How did you find that it can be solved by that method? Or is that your assumption?

Comment: @ Solar Mike It is my assumption that it should be solved by the method. Could you solve it by another method? Because I need the answers to represent and have a plot by Excel.

Comment: This site works by you showing your effort and people will help with corrections as needed. This is not a free "we do your work" service.

Comment: Your right. But I do not have sufficient knowledge to solve my problem. So I need help and tips in this way. Also in my opinion, teaching free can be a kind of charity and can be played an important role in our life.

Comment: Your problem is that you try to apply a numerical scheme to find an analytical solution. In addition, your problem is not well posed. You don't provide initial and boundary conditions. If you look for a general solution to the 1D diffusion equation take a look at this: https://www.uni-muenster.de/imperia/md/content/physik_tp/lectures/ws2016-2017/num_methods_i/heat.pdf

Comment: @J.Fregin Thanks for sharing the reference. It would be useful to approximate the answer.